# SQL Server Function returning data in wrong column

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I came across a User Defined Function (*dbo.AnnualMetrics_ByCat(@StartYear, @EndYear)*) that takes in year range params and contains about 5 CTEs chained together with a query that selects data from them.  The function was coded to return a table like this:

```
MonthYear | CATID | Classification | GeneralClass | TotalUsedVolume | TotalUnusedVolume
--------- | ----- | -------------- | ------------ | --------------- | -----------------
2/1/2010  |  AGR  |  Agricultural  |  NON-RES     |  429.615        | 138.543
```

When the function is called...

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.AnnualMetrics_ByCat(2006,2015) OPTION(MAXRECURSION 200)
```

...it returns a table like this (where "GeneralClass" column is missing, column values are shifted to the right, etc.):

```
MonthYear | CATID | Classification | TotalUsedVolume | TotalUnusedVolume
--------- | ----- | -------------- | --------------- | -----------------
2/1/2010  |  AGR  |  Agricultural  |  NON-RES        |  429.615
```

When the query syntax is cut/paste into an SSMS window and run manually, the correct table structure and values are returned.

My question is, does anyone know what may have caused this?  Dropping the function and recreating it using the original CREATE script resolved the issue, however I am still curious about the origin of the problem.

Comment: Check the the return statement to see if all the columns you want are in it.

Comment: Show us the function.

Comment: Does your function reference a view? Does that view have select *? Does your function have select *?

Comment: @SeanLange The function does not reference a View, but one of the CTEs is populated by a _Select * From dbo.myDatabaseTable_ statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO
USE TestDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE t(x INT, y INT,z INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6);
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw AS SELECT * FROM t;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw; --everything fine here
GO
ALTER TABLE t ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT('blah');
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw; --the new column doesn't show up???
GO
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN y;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.vw; --huh?!?!
GO
USE master;
DROP DATABASE TestDb;
```

The final result

```
x   y   z
1   3   blah
4   6   blah
```

Why are z's values in y and z, which was `INT`, is suddenly "blah"?

The problem is the `SELECT *`. Without a specific column list your view picks the existing column one after the other without looking...

You must refresh/recreate the view.

### UPDATE

I was not clear in this point *The problem is the `SELECT *`*!

What I really meant: **That is the problem, use column names instead of the `*`!**

(Thx Ben J. Boyle)

Comment: Or explicitly name the columns in the select statement.  It's probably better to do that anyway so that the view is only returning the data that it needs to .